# Extracting directory structure from urls

Tags: python

I want to extract the directory hierarchy from a websites url. Not all websites conform to the directory structure. For the websites that do (below), I want to be able to created a python dictionary (below) which reflects the directory hierarchy. How can I go about building a python script which can extract the structure from the urls into a dictionary?

```
Raw data:
http://www.ex.com
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_1
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_2
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_1
http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_2
http://www.ex.com/terms_and_conditions/
http://www.ex.com/Media_Center



Example output:
{'url':'http://www.ex.com', 'sub_dir':[
{'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/', 'sub_dir':[
                        {'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_1'}, {'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_2'}]},
{'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/', 'sub_dir':[
                        {'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_1'},
                        'url':'http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_2']},
{'url':'http://www.ex.com/terms_and_conditions/'},
{'url':'http://www.ex.com/Media_Center'},
]}
```

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

```
For each item:
   if it is a subdir of something else:
       add it to the subdirectory list of that item
   otherwise:
       add it to the main list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a slightly different output format.  First of all, instead of `sub_dir` and `url` keys, the directory structure can be represented as nested dicts where an empty dict is either an empty directory or a file (a leaf in the tree).

For example, the input strings

```
"www.foo.com/images/hellokitty.jpg"
"www.foo.com/images/t-rex.jpg"
"www.foo.com/videos/"
```

would map a directory structure like this:

```
{
    "www.foo.com": {
        "images": {
            "hellokitty.jpg": {},
            "t-rex.jpg": {}
        },
        "videos": {}
    }
}
```

With this model, parsing your data strings is a trivial combination of for loops, an if statement, and some string functions.

**Code:**

```
raw_data = [
    "http://www.ex.com",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_1",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_1/item_2",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_1",
    "http://www.ex.com/product_cat_2/item_2",
    "http://www.ex.com/terms_and_conditions/",
    "http://www.ex.com/Media_Center"
]

root = {}

for url in raw_data:
    last_dir = root
    for dir_name in url.lstrip("htp:/").rstrip("/").split("/"):
        if dir_name in last_dir:
            last_dir = last_dir[dir_name]
        else:
            last_dir[dir_name] = {}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "www.ex.com": {
    "Media_Center": {}, 
    "terms_and_conditions": {}, 
    "product_cat_1": {
      "item_2": {}, 
      "item_1": {}
    }, 
    "product_cat_2": {
      "item_2": {}, 
      "item_1": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code gives wrong results if the order of the elements in the list `raw_data` is changed. Adding `raw_data.sort()` before `root = {}` will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script directly producing the requested output (NB. it takes input from a file; specify the filename as the first (and only) command line argument to the script). NB. using butch's solution and then possibly transforming to this format will likely be both cleaner and faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from urlparse import urlparse
from itertools import ifilter


def match(init, path):
    return path.startswith(init) and init[-1] == "/"

def add_url(tree, url):
    while True:
        if tree["url"] == url:
            return
        f = list(ifilter(lambda t: match(t["url"], url),
                         tree.get("sub_dir", [])))
        if len(f) > 0:
            tree = f[0]
            continue
        sub = {"url": url}
        tree.setdefault("sub_dir", []).append(sub)
        return

def build_tree(urls):
    urls.sort()
    url0 = urls[0]
    tree = {'url': url0}
    for url in urls[1:]:
        add_url(tree, url)
    return tree

def read_urls(filename):
    urls = []
    with open(filename) as fd:
        for line in fd:
            url = urlparse(line.strip())
            urls.append("".join([url.scheme, "://", url.netloc, url.path]))
    return urls


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    urls = read_urls(sys.argv[1])
    tree = build_tree(urls)
    print("%r" % tree)
```